# What IDE's are avaliable for programming in elementary?

Tags: programming, ide

I use Scratch for programming in elementary OS, and then Terminal to run it.

While this works fairly well, I would like to know which IDEs are available for elementary OS? What are the drawbacks and advantages?

#### Please post your suggestions one per answer as a Community Wiki post.

Comment: Perhaps we can collect answers in a community wiki?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad because any Linux IDE can be used on elementary. There are thousands of IDEs that work on Linux — many programming languages have one, if not multiple ones. “What IDEs are available *in* elementary” (excluding third-party packages) would be reasonably scoped, but boring. What IDEs are available for a specific programming language could work.

Comment: @Gilles even the latter would be really broad. I've voted to close for the same reason.

Comment: I don't think anyone wants to start to list all IDEs available, rather only the ones that work and integrate well under elementary. This makes the question quite opinion-based, but not broad as in "please list 1000 Linux IDEs"...

Comment: IDEs for all languages or for a specific one? This question is *way* too broad.

Comment: What IDE does the elementary OS developer team use?

Comment: As I know, there are some developing with Scratch, some with Gnome Builder, others with Sublime Text, ...

Answer (score 6):

elementary OS developers use a text editor by personal preferences. mine is sublime text with of course terminal to build. This gives developer the advantages to know also about the build process and what is used like libraries.

There is also this : https://github.com/PerfectCarl/ValaBinding
this is a vala binding for monodevelop IDE. i haven't tried it but you could if you want.

Comment: I think it's pointless to have one answer for all. Rather have one answer for each IDE so people can vote and comment on the merrits of each individual IDE.

Answer (score 5):

### [Atom](https://atom.io)

> Atom is a text editor that's modern, approachable, yet hackable to the core—a tool you can customize to do anything but also use productively without ever touching a config file.

#### Features:

> - Built on web technologies for easy hacking of the editor itself
> - Wide array of packages to extend functionality
> - Theming support
> - Built-in git-support
> - Multiple panes (split view), file system browser, autocompletion

[Download a `.deb` file here](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.0.0)

[There is also theme available to make Atom fit in with elementary.](https://atom.io/themes/elementary-light-ui)

Comment: I still very much prefer [VS Code](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.visualstudio.code), which has virtually all of the advantages you mentioned too.