# Is there an elementary IDE for developing elementary applications?

Tags: applications, programming

Is there an IDE that is recommended by the elementary OS developers?

Comment: Hey please look at this : http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/150/what-ides-are-avaliable-for-programming-in-elementary/154#154

have a nice day :)

Comment: @kay I'd refer you back to the comment on your answer as per that question. I think maybe your answer is better off here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Scratch + Terminal + Developer Libraries

Yep that's the set of software which are the official elementary SDK, as you can find out [here](https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started).

Scratch is better than notepad (that's included with Windows), but is still a newcomer. You can later give these text editors a try:

- [Geany](http://www.geany.org)
- [Atom](http://www.atom.io)
- [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com)
- [Gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit)

All run in elementary. All are Open Source *except* **Sublime Text** but you can run an evaluation version and then purchase a license if you want.

Also the **Github's Atom** is based on Web Technologies and is the most customizable and heaviest of all four.